# Change name of column vector in R

Tags: r

[image]
I have a vector here, these are number of customer per month and I am trying to name them as January,February,... but it doesn't work. Here is my code, plz have a look and show me what is wrong

```
Numberofcust <- c(count(Feb),count(Jan),count(Mar),count(Apr),count(May),count(Jun),count(July),count(Aug),count(Sep),count(Oct),count(Nov),count(Dec))
colnames(Numberofcust)<-c("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")
IT CLAIMS THAT " Error in colnames(Numberofcust, "January", "February", "March", "April",  : 
  unused arguments ("March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
```

Comment: Please look at the examples in `?colnames`. Try `colnames(Numberofcust) <- c('January'....)` or use `month.name` inbuilt constant.

Comment: Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("January", "February", "March",  : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions.

Comment: What is `class(Numberofcust)` ? Try using `names(Numberofcust) <- month.name`

Comment: It works. Ty, ya the best